# TitleView and RightBarButtonItem on all Navigation Controllers

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am developing a navigation based application and I have a custom titleView and a rightBarButtonItem for the navigationBar which i want in all navigation items of my application (like a logo and a menu button which you can access from all views).

Is there any good practice to implement this rather than manually setting the titleView and the rightBarButtonItem every time i push a new viewController ? I am using monotouch.dialog but any tips are welcome, since this seems more like a question about the sdk.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to first ask yourself if you really *need* a UINavigationBar that is directly correlated to the UINavigationController or whether you'd like a static UIToolbar with your content.

Alternatively, you could do what @MartinMoizard is referring to which is subclass UIViewController. I've provided samples for both below. Cheers!

```
public class MyToolbar : UIToolbar
{
    public MyToolbar()
        : base()
    {
        var myTitle = MyCustomUIlabel();
        var myButton = MyCustomUIButton();

        this.SetItems(new UIBarButtonItem[] { 
        myTitle, 
        new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace),
        myButton });
    }
}


public class MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    public MyViewController()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        //
        // .. setup your code hurr' dawg
        //

        this.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = myRightButton;
        this.NavigationItem.Title = "My Title";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the examples ! i think i will follow @MartinMoizard's approach, because i still need the back button to be available on the Navigation controller.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like inheritance would be a solution for you.

You should maybe consider doing a UIViewController mother class that deals with setting the titleView and the RightBarButton item and then all the UIViewController from your app would inherit from that class.